# Jest Not Find Mock Module

Tags: jestjs

My folder structure:

```
├──wrapper.js 
├──lib
|  └──zwportal.js
├── __tests__
│   └── wrapper.test.js
── __mocks__
│   └── zwportal.js
|
```

In `wrapper.js`:

```
const portal = require('./lib/zwportal.js')
```

Since zwportal.js is very complex, I use a mock put in the **mocks** folder. So in my test:

```
'use strict';
// Mocking dependencies

jest.mock('../lib/zwportal.js');
zwportal = require('../lib/zwportal.js');
```

Hower, when I run:

```
jest
```

it says:

```
 FAIL  __tests__/wrapper.test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Cannot find module 'abstract-socket' from 'avro-utils.js'
```

Actually, those files, `abstract-socket` and `avro-utils`, are in the original "non mocked" `zwportal.js`. It seems that jest does not mock this file. Why?

**EDIT**

In my test suite, if I write:

```
jest.mock('../lib/zwportal.js', () => {});
zwportal = require('../lib/zwportal.js');
```

no problems occur. However, I need to mock with some behaviour the mock.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm stuck with a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

Manual mocks are defined by writing a module in a **mocks**/ subdirectory immediately adjacent to the module. For example, to mock a module called user in the models directory, create a file called user.js and put it in the models/**mocks** directory.

try to move **mocks** directory to lib directory